# Reputation gone wild: It happened again

Tags: bug

Over the past week or so I have occasionally received notification messages with very large numbers in them, e.g.

[image]

125 points sounded great, almost too good to be true.  I would expect this only perhaps from winning a bounty, except for that I never answer them.  Yet upon opening the rep inbox, I got another surprise:

[image]

It looks like the +125 was a false flag, possibly a bug or really bizarre A/B test.

Can someone shed some light on what is happening here?

Comment: It is the same issue as reported by the question that I closed it as a duplicate of. The achievements notification shows a bunch o' rep as being earned, but you click on the drop-down and are disappointed to find out that there are no new notifications. It's reporting stale data. Has been doing this for several days now; no news yet.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for letting us know.  Sadly, I won't be getting any real rep from my question as it is a duplicate.

Comment: Nobody gets rep on Meta.